# How to apply the function `flextable` on a list of tables?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have this list **L** of tables ( I used **df1** and **df2** to produce the tables **t1** and **t2** but in my real case we have just tables to work on them ) :

```
df1 = data.frame(male = c(0,1,0,0,1,1), female = c(0,0,0,1,1,0))

df2 = data.frame(adult = c(1,1,0,0), teenager = c(1,1,1,1) )

t1 = table(df1)

t2 = table(df2)

L = list(t1,t2)
```

And I wish to apply the function `flextable` to produce a **table** for each table of this list **L** (meaning I need to convert each table into a dataframe and then apply **lapply** to make it work. However I wasn't able to do it the right way.)

appreciate the help and thanks.

Comment: Maël : flextable only works on dataframes .not tables.

Comment: The list includes tables. not dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lapply()` to apply a function to a list. Since `flextable()` only works on dataframes, you need to convert the table to a dataframe first:

```r
lapply(L, function(x) {
  flextable::flextable(as.data.frame(x))
})
```